# How to cluster data series with different intervals?

Tags: time-series

I have data, effectively a set of event series, which should cluster well over their overlaps, but have different intervals where the data is available. This can be simplified to overlapping noisy $sin$ and $cos$ datasets:

```
SeedRandom[9];
ListPlot[
 Table[
  With[{offset = RandomChoice[{0, 5}]},
   Table[{t, f[t] + RandomReal[]/2},
   {t, -5 + offset, 5 + offset, 0.05}]],
  {f, RandomChoice[{Sin, Cos}, 15]}]]
```

[image]

It should be intuitively clear that the data clusters according to the function used.

When I try `FindClusters` on this, it doesn't cluster according to the function, but the offset:

```
SeedRandom[9];
FindClusters[
 Table[
  With[{offset = RandomChoice[{0, 5}]},
   Table[{t, f[t] + RandomReal[]/2},
     {t, -5 + offset, 5 + offset, 0.05}] -> {f, offset}],
  {f, RandomChoice[{Sin, Cos}, 15]}],
 2]

(* {{{Sin, 5}, {Cos, 5}, {Sin, 5}, {Cos, 5}, {Cos, 5}, {Sin, 5}, {Sin, 5}, {Cos, 5}},
    {{Cos, 0}, {Cos, 0}, {Sin, 0}, {Cos, 0}, {Sin, 0}, {Cos, 0}, {Cos, 0}}} *)
```

This is clearly not what I intended. Also, feeding `EventSeries` or `TimeSeries` doesn't seem to work with `FindClusters`. What to do?

**EDIT**:

It would seem that if I reformulate my data to be regularly formed with `Missing[]` values, using `"Multinormal"` or `"GaussianMixture"` methods for `MissingValueSynthesis` produce the expected result, but I have absolutely no idea if this happens for the right reasons:

```
SeedRandom[9];
FindClusters[
 Table[
  With[{offset = RandomChoice[{0, 5}]},
   Table[
     If[-5 + offset <= t <= 5 + offset, f[t] + RandomReal[]/2, Missing[]],
     {t, -5, 10, 0.05}] -> {f, offset}],
  {f, RandomChoice[{Sin, Cos}, 15]}],
 2, MissingValueSynthesis -> "Multinormal"]

(* {{{Sin, 5}, {Sin, 5}, {Sin, 0}, {Sin, 0}, {Sin, 5}, {Sin, 5}},
    {{Cos, 0}, {Cos, 0}, {Cos, 5}, {Cos, 5}, {Cos, 0}, {Cos, 0}, {Cos,  5}, {Cos, 0}, {Cos, 5}}} *)
```

Answer (score 1):

I assume you want to gather all dataset that have the same Cos[x+offset] behavior.

Toward this aim we may define a function that checks if all the y values of a data set are within an interval of some size around the cosine:

```
test[dat_, off_] := AllTrue[dat, Abs[1.2 Cos[ #[[1]] + off] - #[[2]]] < 1 &]
```

We create the data sets by:

```
SeedRandom[9];
dat = Table[
  With[{offset = RandomChoice[{0, 5}]}, 
   Table[{t, f[t] + RandomReal[]/2}, {t, offset, offset + 10, 
     0.05}]], {f, RandomChoice[{Sin, Cos}, 15]}];
```

To get an idea of the offset, we need to plot the first few datasets:

```
ListLinePlot[{dat[[1]], dat[[4]]}]
```

(* The image upload is not working *)

From this we guess offsets of: 0 and -1.3.

to get all datasets with an offset of 0:

```
off=0;
dat1 = Select[dat, test[#, off] &];
```

and their position inside dat:

```
Position[dat, #] & /@ dat1

(* {2, 3, 4, 7, 8, 10, 11, 12, 15} *)
```

The same for offset:[[1,1]] -1.3

```
dat2 = Select[dat, test[#, off] &];
Position[dat, #][[1, 1]] & /@ dat2

(* {1, 5, 6, 9, 13, 14} *)
```

This accounts for all the datasets.